# is it possible in blazor webassembly to load and navigate a page without specifying a page directive or a minimal one

Tags: lazy-loading, blazor-webassembly, razor-class-library, dynamic-assemblies

I use this [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to load to `Customer` pages from two assemblies: `Software1/Customer` and `Software2/Customer` that Software1 and Software2 are two **Razor class libraries** that I Load `Customer` from them. I load each of the assemblies based on their first segment of their path. that is `/Software1` or `/Software2`.

Now my question is it possible that I keep the paths `Software1/Customer` and `Software2/Customer` in the address bar but I have no `@page` directive above `Customer` razor files or at most a page directive like this:  `@page "/Customer"` but keep the original paths: `Software1/Customer` and `Software2/Customer` in the browser?